# Displaying updated date for entry

Tags: datetime, postdate

I want to display the date an entry has been updated if it is later than the post date. So I've tried this:

```
   {% if entry.dateUpdated >= entry.post %}
      Updated on {{ entry.dateUpdated.format('j M y') }}
   {% endif %}
```

But the date updated displays even if it is earlier. Is this because the date is not strictly a value as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date fields in Craft are returned as `DateTime` objects, so you need to convert these to a string to be able to compare them.

The best way of doing this is to use the `yyyy-mm-dd` format as this makes it is easy to compare dates.

So your comparison would become:

```
   {% if (entry.dateUpdated|date('Y-m-d')) >= (entry.postDate|date('Y-m-d')) %}
      Updated on {{ entry.dateUpdated.format('j M y') }}
   {% endif %}
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Just for reference there's a missing closing bracket - ie. (entry.postDate|date('Y-m-d'))

Comment: Thanks for picking that up. I've just edited it to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

You're not checking against a valid field there - try using `entry.postDate` instead of `entry.post`